# Kubernetes :: Restart terminated pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jobs

I'm using Kubernetes to run jobs with a `RestartPolicy` to `Never`.

Sometime, I would like to be able to debug a failed/terminated pod. In some way, I'm trying to find how restart it with a `sleep XXX` command to connect (exec) to the container and get the same state.

In Docker this is something doable using `docker ps --all` and then `docker start X` but I didn't find something similar with `kubectl` or the `client-go`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `client-go` as I have no experience there. But if I understood the question correctly, you can check the reason of the failure:

`kubectl get pods` (if you do not see your pod here add `--all-namespaces`)

```
NAME              READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
pi-c2x4r          0/1       Completed   0          19m
pi-test-c5hln     0/1       Error       0          16m`
```

And then run:
`kubectl describe pod pi-test-c5hln` (name of your pod).

`kubectl logs pi-test-c5hln`

You can also find more information when you run:

`kubectl describe job *job name*`

You can find useful information about Jobs and how to work with them (including cleanup, termination and patterns) in [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup).
Not sure if it needs to be added, but terminating is ongoing process, so you can work with the pod after it goes from terminating to other status (error, completed).